# Prove logarithmic identity

Tags: logarithms, proof-explanation

I have to prove that $a^{\log_b(x)} = x^{\log_b(a)}$ without using the base change rule.  How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- take logarithms base $b$ of both sides
- $\log_b\left(c^d\right) = d\, \log_b(c)$

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I should have looked at log properties closer and thought about it more.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\log_bx=y,x=b^y$

$x^{\log_ba}=(b^{\log_ba})^y=a^y$

The last identity can be established by setting $\log_ba=z,a=b^z=b^{\log_ba}$